# PHP XML feed usage from Twitter

Tags: php, xml, twitter

The following code should take the xml feed from Twitter and echo the results.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/QuiteCheesedOff.xml?count=6');

$tweets = $xml->xpath("/statuses/status");

foreach($tweets as $tweet) {

    $text = $tweet->text;
    $date = $tweet->created_at;

    echo '<div>' . $text . '</div>' . '<b>' . $date . '</b>';
}

?>
```

Instead it returns this.

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/QuiteCheesedOff.xml?count=6)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in
>   /home/divethe1/public_html/robin-knight.com/wp-content/themes/RIKsoft/index.php
>   on line 142

Comment: It could be related to rate limiting: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

Comment: IT's working now for an unknown reason

Comment: IT's not working again for an unknown reason

Answer (score 0):

You might try using DOMDocument->load( $url ).
The URL for the Twitter feed is also available without SSL, try that if SSL gives you grief and you don't need the secure version.